# copying and renaming files

Tags: python

I'm trying to create multiple copies of a file, by copying and renaming it based on the contents of a csv file.

The code below seems to be producing the correct result when I just print the commands to be run, however, when actually execusting the command, noting is copied, and I just end up with many open and blank cmd windows. Is this a Windows permission issue?

```
import os
import csv 
file_location1 = "blank.mpp" 
csv_file_location ="all_projects_2014.csv" 

with open(csv_file_location,'r') as f: 
    contents = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in contents: 
        second_file = str(row) 
        second_file = second_file.translate(None, '[\']')+'.mpp' 
        command = "cp %s %s" % (file_location1, second_file) 
        os.system(command) 
        #print command
```

Comment: Is `cp` a valid windows command?  I would recommend `shutil.copy` instead of calling a shell command because it is more portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you used copy method given by python [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

```
from shutil import copy
shutil.copy(file_location1, second_file)


>>> help(shutil.copy)
Help on function copy in module shutil:
copy(src, dst)
    Copy data and mode bits ("cp src dst").
    The destination may be a directory.

>>> help(shutil.copy2)
Help on function copy2 in module shutil:
copy2(src, dst)
    Copy data and all stat info ("cp -p src dst").
    The destination may be a directory.
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - how do I install shutil? I'm using Canopy and it is not listed in package manager as an option to install?

Comment: shutil is a part of python std lib since 2.6, could you please check your version.

Comment: 2.7.3 | 64-bit | (default, Dec  2 2013, 16:09:43) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Trying to import from shutil gives me error. I'm running Windows8.1 and use Canopy as my Python environment - where can I find my Python folder - perhaps the PATH etc is not correct on my system?

Comment: could you please try import shutil and check it works ?

Comment: Hi, please help me with importing - when I use Canopy packagemanger, there is no shutil package to import in the list of available packages. I went ahead and copied the source of the shutil.py lib and manually dropped it in all the Lib folders I could find under Canopy/Python on my PC, but it did not work

Comment: Do, you how to go to command prompt in windows, then to python interactive prompt ?

Comment: Easy way is in your script, put this line and run and confirm. `import shutil`

Comment: You know how to import!  You have `import os` and `import csv` in the script in your original question!

Comment: Funny thing - the script fails if I tried to "import copy from shutil" but if I only import shutil, it worked.

Comment: you should import as `from shutil import copy`  or `import shutil.copy`

Answer (score 0):

`cp` is not a valid command for Windows. You have to use `copy` command in Windows.

As Different Platforms has different commands so i recomend you to use [shutil](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-shutil.html).copy(...)

If you only want to run code on Windows then try this:

```
import os
import csv 
file_location1 = "blank.mpp" 
csv_file_location ="all_projects_2014.csv" 

with open(csv_file_location,'r') as f: 
    contents = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in contents: 
        second_file = str(row) 
        second_file = second_file.translate(None, '[\']')+'.mpp' 
        command = "copy \"%s\" \"%s\"" % (file_location1, second_file) 
        os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed to copy, and it seems to be working, except, it still opens a cmd window which I have to close manually. Would like to try shutil, but don't know how to add that to canopy/python?

Comment: If importing `shutil` doesn't work then try placing [this shutil file](http://zeetechteam.com/adnan/shutil.py) with your code and import `shutil` to use `shutil.copy(...)`

Comment: If this doesn't work then place whole file content before your code and use `copy(src, dst)` to copy file